# How to express a polynomial as a point in a given basis.

Tags: polynomials, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials, change-of-basis

Assume a polynomial basis that is given by $[1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots,x^{10}]$. Express the polynomial $$f(x) = 1+3x^2-4x^3+x^4+x^6+11x^{7}-5x^8-2x^9+x^{10}$$ as a point in this basis.

(a) Are the elements of the basis linearly independent?

(b) Are the elements of the basis orthogonal?

Comment: What bases? Do you mean the basis elements of the given basis?

Comment: Just take the coefficients. They form the coordinates of the point. The elements of the basis are linear independent (which must be because otherwise they would not form a basis). But I am not sure, how we can apply a scalar product to check the orthogonality. Maybe this works via integrals similar to the integrals used to calculate the coefficients of a Fourier-series, but I do not know the details.

Comment: You need an inner product to answer the second part, but you haven’t provided one in your question.